# MySQL View Multiple Tables Duplicates

Tags: mysql, join, view, duplicates

I'm trying to create a view with multiple tables that contain uniform Date / Account data but different data observations.

```
VISITS(Date, CompanyName, Visits)
SEARCHES(Date, CompanyName, Searches)
REPORTS(Date, CompanyName, Reports)

CREATE VIEW V AS 
    SELECT
        v.Date,
        v.CompanyName as Company,
        s.PageViews as Searches,
        r.PageViews as Reports
    FROM 
        Visits_r1 v
    LEFT JOIN
        Searches_r s ON v.CompanyName = s.CompanyName
    LEFT JOIN
        Reports_r r ON v.CompanyName = r.CompanyName
    WHERE
        v.Date = s.Date
    AND
        v.Date = r.Date;
```

However the issue that i'm encountering is duplication of data; I would want the unique amount of Visits, Searches, Reports by Company and Date.  Is this possible?

Comment: Please, add the types of the columns to your question. So, for what i understand now, you want to group by (date, companyName) and get the total visits, searches and reports for that tuple?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to group by **Date** and **companyName** after joining the tables and use the **SUM()** aggregation method for get the totals of every (date, company) group.

```
CREATE VIEW V AS
    SELECT
        v.Date,
        v.CompanyName as Company,
        SUM(s.Searches) AS TotalSearches,
        SUM(r.Reports) AS TotalReports,
        SUM(v.Visits) AS TotalVisits
    FROM
        Visits AS v
    LEFT JOIN
        Searches AS s ON s.CompanyName = v.CompanyName AND s.Date = v.Date
    LEFT JOIN
        Reports AS r ON r.CompanyName = v.CompanyName AND r.Date = v.Date
    GROUP BY
        v.Date, v.CompanyName;
```